# Public key for /etc/ssh/whatever does not match private key - but it does

Tags: ssh, public-key, rsa

When I start my ssh service (on a Devuan Chimaera Linux box), I get the warnings:

```
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does not match private key
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key does not match private key
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key does not match private key
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does not match private key
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key does not match private key
Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key does not match private key
```

So, I checked the RSA keys using the method described here:
[How to check if an RSA public / private key pair match](https://serverfault.com/q/426394/)
... and they do match.

What's going on? I should mention SSH'ing using RSA keys seems to work.

Comment: You may need to recreate your host keys: `rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key* ; dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server; service ssh restart`

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1925